# how to add parent align for tab TabWidget?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

i am writing java code to create a tabs.i have done that.but now i want the tab widget to be in the lower part of the screen.i hope this will be achived by adding this code. `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` let me know how to add this coding.i want similar look like this http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android.html

TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(this);

```
    tabHost.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(ContactManager.this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

   rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, android.R.id.tabs);
    rl.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    tabHost.addView(rl);

    TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
    tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
    rl.addView(tabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    frameLayout.setPadding(0, 55, 0, 0);


    rl.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    tabHost.setup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your layout with XML it's a lot easier.  You will need custom made tab images because the stock ones don't look right at the bottom of the screen.